The android app consistently crashes, displaying an error stating that the "libruntime.so" file cannot be located
I have been trying to implement spline3d inside a FrameLayout (because i need to display other buttons and featuers in the same fragment) which inturn is inside a fragment but i am gettting errors when i run the application showing 'Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libruntime.so" not found'.
logcat: error
this is the code that i am using:
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val splineContainer = view.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.spline_container)

        splineContainer.addView(
            SplineView(requireContext()).apply {
                // fetching from cloud
                loadUrl("url")

                // fetching from local
                // loadResource(R.raw.scene)
            })
        return view

    }

}

i have added 'android:extractNativeLibs="true"' to the manifest file but still the error persists.

libruntime.so may not be located at the expected location.

yeah i tried adding the file in the location [src/main/jniLibs] under different architectures.  but I still was not able to stop crashes as the libruntime.so file that I added was an empty file.
